# Can Someone Identify a Fantasy Book Based Mostly on a Particular Drinking Scene?

Tags: story-identification, books

I am trying to figure out what book or series of book this specific scene comes from.  I have wracked my brain over and over, and while I can recall a few details here and there, if I'm being honest, I cannot recall much meaningful of the book I am looking for.  However, there is one specific occurrence/scene that is quite strong.  I will detail it below.

In said scene, a group of "elders" for a town or village of peoples that are great at stealth and/or stealing are approached by one of the main characters.  The way our characters get to this village is such:  They discover one of the people from this village, and bribe / convince them to take them to their home by loaning them a knife or dagger.  Once at the hidden village, one of the main characters ends up in a drinking challenge with the elders.  On the topic of these elders, there are at least two men, and one woman.  The woman is very raucous and flirtatious.

I will try to think of some more details, but these are the most prominent things I have remembered, even after discussing it with my partner.  The only other thing I believe I can recall is that it was more fantasy-leaning than sci-fi-leaning.

Thank you in advance for any assistance!

Comment: I have a vague memory of a book where the protagonist needs the assistance of the "stealth" people to help him steal something, or infiltrate some guarded compound for another reason. He goes to the village to try and recruit them. I also recall it as not being a very good book!